# Travis CI giving error to a test in which it was previously building successfully

Tags: python, git, code-coverage, travis-ci

Travis CI showed a weird behaviour after I tried to integrate with coverage. Before trying to use coverage the build was okay with all the tests. Now suddenly it doesn't locate the file

[image]

here is the .travis.yml file

```
 #language to use for app
language: python
 -- "3.6"

script:
 - virtualEnv/run_travis.sh

# whitelist
branches:
  only:
    - master
    - flask_dev_branch

#dependacies and libraries to install
install: pip install -r virtualEnv/requirements.txt

after_success:
  - coveralls
```

And the file run_travis.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
python tests/test_shopping_cart.py > /dev/null &
nosetests --with-coverage
```

Also an image of the directory with the files included

[image]

All this started happening after trying to configure coverage.

Answer (score 1):

Your `tests` subdirectory is inside `virtualEnv` and the current directory is the parent of `virtualEnv`. Run

```
python virtualEnv/tests/test_shopping_cart.py
```

PS. And please don't show screenshots — copy text.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the `requirements.txt` is not in the `virtualEnv` directory.

Comment: Hallo, thanks @invicibly cool but its there. the second last file in that last image screenshot